# How to sum a field

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a query to display the total marks for a student’s assessments in all sessions for 2019. The result should include the student names, unit code, the sum of marks given for their assessments and the final grade given. It should be sorted by the student’s last name and first name, session, and unit code.

This is the query used to get `UnitCode` added, but the result just adds every `UnitCode`.

```
SELECT Distinct STUDENT.StudentID, STUDENT.LastName, STUDENT.FirstName, 
  UNIT_ENROLMENT.Year, UNIT_ENROLMENT.Session, UNIT.UnitCode
FROM STUDENT 
    INNER JOIN UNIT_ENROLMENT
        USING (StudentID)
    INNER JOIN UNIT
        USING (UnitCode)
WHERE STUDENT.StudentID = 31908266;
```

I've been at it for hours with joins, but I am having issues with `UnitCode` and getting the marks sum.

Database Structure:[image: Database Structure:]

Comment: post your query.

Comment: Please post the query you tried, the results you got, the results you expected, and you may also have to post source data

Comment: I posted the query of where i am at. Just trying to get the UnitCode into the results has been challenging for me.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid its the last one in the select list already

Comment: It's not clear from your diagram what the join between `UNIT_ENROLMENT` and `UNIT` is. I suggest you inspect the data in these tables and see if you can find out what the join column(s) is between these two

Comment: You definitely don't want to use a cross join

Comment: _Also_, please post what type if database this is? Is it MySql?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid oh sorry, i did tag phpmyadmin. 

Right, there isn't a join between UNIT and UNIT_ENROLMENT.

So my first step should be making one?

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a database. I just googled it and it looks like it's a front end to `MySQL`. Please add that tag. Yes you need to join between those tables, otherwise you get a "cross join", which is what you're seeing right now, where you just get every combination of everything. Looking at your digram again, it looks like you first need to join `UNIT_ENROLMENT` to `UNIT_OFFERING`. Write some SQL to do that. Then _after_ you've done that, tested it, looked at the data and are happy, add another join from `UNIT_OFFERING` to `UNIT`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid awesome! i'll get onto that now :) 
There is however a join between UNIT_ENROLMENT and UNIT_OFFERING via UnitOfferingID

Comment: Yes. That’s what you need to do first. Join those tables on that column.

Comment: damn im heaving a lot of trouble just trying to join these, can't add a foreign key to an existing table?

Comment: You don't need to add a foreign key, you just need to take the SQL statement you have already posted, remove the cross join to `UNIT`, and instead add an inner join from `UNIT_ENROLMENT` to `UNIT_OFFERING`

Comment: Foreign keys enforce valid data, but are not necessary to join tables in a select statement.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i tried it that way but unfortunately i still get repeated results :/

Comment: Please edit the question and add the query you tried.

Comment: Done, sorry about the formatting, im new to this site haha

Comment: As I said in my prior comments, _remove the cross join to UNIT, and instead add an inner join from `UNIT_ENROLMENT` to `UNIT_OFFERING`_. Your SQL query still has `UNIT` and it doesn't have `UNIT_OFFERING`

Comment: This isn't a [tag:sequel] question. Sequel is an ORM for Ruby.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" and "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)".